# Dalekjs open() method hangs randomly

Tags: javascript, user-interface, testing, dalekjs

I have following issue:

it seems that the open() hangs randomly when opening a webapp, which is running on an internal server. (testserver) If i try the open() method for another website like (http://derstandard.at/) this issue does not occur.

is their a possibility to try to reopen the website with the waitFor method?

cheers izocan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question is provided [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dalekjs/wCmEKfDvxYQ)